# How to set buffering frames?

Tags: timeline

In User Preferences > Editing > Allow Negative Frames > checked and saved.

I want to let physics items to settle before rendering an animation both in cycles and with OpenGL. But How do I tell Blender to start playing at frame -10 yet start rendering after 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of what type of physics you want.

For example, cloth simulation. In cache settings you can set start value negative:

[image]

You can noted, that this value limited by 1, but this not right. Click in center of value "Start" and enter negative value from keyboard. It's not a bug, many values in blender can be redefined in this way, for example 200% render resolution.

In other types of physics there is another option "offset". Like in water simulation. Offset shift all frames in time back and forward.

[image]

And of course, Allow Negative Frames in this case is useless.

Comment: I didn't work at first as it didn't buffer when I started at frame 1. Figuring it went from -100 to 0 buffering. But it did when I started the animation at frame 100 and it buffered from 0-99.